# How to capture all 13 digits after that regex non-capture group

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, local-storage

I'm trying to capture a `SKU` of a product from `localstorage` in javascript

the item is a html string and i'm trying to figure out a `regex` that capture that `SKU id`

the `localstorage` return looks like this:

`<li class="cart__item">SKU: MLB2046549757 | NAME: Notebook Multilaser Legacy Book Pc310 Preta 14.1 , Intel Celeron N3000  4gb De Ram 64gb Ssd, Intel Hd Graphics 1366x768px Windows 10 Home | PRICE: $1415</li><li class="cart__item">SKU: MLB2046549757 | NAME: Notebook Multilaser Legacy Book Pc310 Preta 14.1 , Intel Celeron N3000  4gb De Ram 64gb Ssd, Intel Hd Graphics 1366x768px Windows 10 Home | PRICE: $1415</li>`

i tried `(?:SKU\: ){13}` regex to get e.g. `MLB2046549757` SKU id but it didn't worked.

I need to capture all 13 digits after `SKU:`  and save it in an array.

Anyone have an idea how could i do that?

Comment: Is the `<li>` item really duplicated twice like that or did you make a copy-paste error writing your question?

Comment: Actually is really duplicated, the item saved on localstorage, gets all ```<li>``` inside an ```<ol>``` it could be a different or even the same item already inside ```<li>```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're confident that you have consistent content try: `/(?<=SKU:\s)[\dA-Z]{13}/g`

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('li');

let SKU = [...items].flatMap(li => li.textContent.match(/(?<=SKU:\s)[\dA-Z]{13}/g));

console.log(SKU)
```

```html
<li class="cart__item">SKU: MLB2046549757 | NAME: Notebook Multilaser Legacy Book Pc310 Preta 14.1 , Intel Celeron N3000 4gb De Ram 64gb Ssd, Intel Hd Graphics 1366x768px Windows 10 Home | PRICE: $1415</li>
<li class="cart__item">SKU: MLB2046585666 | NAME: Notebook Multilaser Legacy Book Pc310 Preta 14.1 , Intel Celeron N3000 4gb De Ram 64gb Ssd, Intel Hd Graphics 1366x768px Windows 10 Home | PRICE: $1415</li>
```

Comment: You're very welcome @Rafo , I updated it with a negative lookbehind on the SKU. It's the same result but more specific and safer.

Comment: You could also use `\S` instead of `\dA-Z` if you can't guarantee that the SKU consists only of upper-case letters and numbers.

Comment: True, but that would include commas, question marks, etc., and same for `\w`, probably `a-z` as well?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(SKU:\s)(.{13})

(?<=SKU:\s)(.{13})
```

2nd regex will result only the 13 positions after SKU:
See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Sw6uBl/1)

-Cheers!

Comment: actually i just wanted to get the code after ```SKU: ```, so the first group must be a non-capture group. But thanks for your time and answer! regex is really hard to me and i'm getting better with every help from you

Comment: See 2nd regex which will result the part you only want. Please mark as solution if it is the solution you need.